# Simple Git Deployment Workflow

Tags: php, git, deployment, github

I want to deploy from git to production.  In that case, should I simply be cloning from git?

I know that clone duplicates the history of the project, which I don't really need in a production environment.  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `git archive` to create a `tar`-file just containing the files of the commit you select and extract it in your production environment.  I prefer cloning, since this makes later updates a lot easier (you can just `git fetch`, look what you'll have to adjust to make the update work and `git merge`).  This safes a lot of trouble than doing `git archive` again, moving the old tree, extracting the new one, finding differences between old and new, adopt configuration changes etc., …

Answer (score 0):

Clone to temp folder and then rsync to desired location excluding whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a branch for deployment and push your updates to it whenever you wanna deploy, check this article [here](http://krisjordan.com/essays/setting-up-push-to-deploy-with-git).

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a node.js script that handled deploying code, but it became unwieldy to manage once I had more than one project with specific requirements. I recommend using https://stackahoy.io/ (Warning: I'm on the Stackahoy team and would be happy to answer any Q's.). It's totally free for 1 repo and unlimited branches. It allows you to:

- Maintain deployments for your git repositories in one place
- Maintain static configuration files (stuff you keep in the .gitignore file)
- Preform post-deployment scripts
- Securely and instantly deploy your code based on the branch that was pushed and see real-time logs as it deploys.
- Deploy to multiple servers at once (good for load-balanced applications)